# Pusher in background job is outpacing my app - missing JS notifications

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sidekiq, pusher

I'm moving imports of excel files (often large, often small) into the background using Sidekiq, and alerting the user when the importing is complete using Pusher.

At first, in the 'synchronous' flow (Rails app here), it will kick off the excel import, and then it will redirect to a dashboard page which will receive notifications from Pusher when the importing is done.

The problem is the Sidekiq-Pusher flow sometimes goes faster than the redirect to the dashboard page. My JavaScript subscriber won't be initialized in time to receive the message that is being published from within the background process. So the client gets nothing.

Does Pusher offer a way to delay publishing a message until there is a subscriber? Or does Pusher offer a way to 'stockpile' messages until the subscriber springs to life to consume them? Or maybe there is a simpler solution here I have not thought of?

Fyi, I don't want the background job to sleep for a few seconds to make sure the client is ready, and I don't want to use Pusher to trigger a refresh (i.e. save something in a DB, then refresh to display it).

I am happy to provide code samples if desired.

EDIT:

I'm certainly open to using something else besides Pusher if something else can solve my problem.

Comment: Hey, without being logged in to the Pusher account, how you could get the message to the client side. I mean if I'm not logged in to the pusher account using my email-id and password, I'm not getting the message since the connection is not active. How can we do that?

Comment: You could use webhooks to check if the channel is vacated. If it is just wait until someone is subscribed :)

Answer (score 0):

Invoke the worker after 1 or 2 seconds from the current time so that it gets invoked and show the message after being redirected to the landing page.

```
TestProcess.perform_at(2.seconds.from_now,parameters)
```

It will work as expected. Hope it helps :)

Comment: Ideally I don't want to rely on server side delays (whether inside the background job or for the job itself), because I want to account for the possibility that users may have browser/ connection hiccups where it could take a while for the Rails redirect to go through. Thank you for bringing up this point though.